# Set Initial Screen Image for Xcode Tab Bar App

Tags: xcode, tabbar

New to Xcode so I'll try to explain my needs correctly.

I've used the default tab bar template to create an app.  The first tab is set up with a table view.  I would like the initial screen to mimic the splash screen and not show the table view until the user clicks the button on the tab bar.  I would like to have the tab bar not have a default button pressed (highlighted) until the user clicks it.

So, in essence, I would like to have my initial view after the app loads to mimic the splash screen view but with the tab bar available at the bottom with no tab selected by default.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: [iOS Recipes](http://pragprog.com/book/cdirec/ios-recipes) from the Pragmatic Bookshelf has, as its first recipe, a solution to this problem (at least showing a splash screen and doing a nice transition, it shouldn't be too big a leap to apply that to your situation).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used the following code. In order for it to work it must be included in an app delegate. I'm using OSX and an image as well but you can use a UIView instead. See tutorials by SDK or iPhone for this. Code below:

**.h class**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSImageView *name;
}

- (IBAction)img1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)img2:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m class**

```
import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)img1:(id)sender 
{
    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]; [name setImage:img];
}

- (IBAction)img2:(id)sender 
{ 
    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"]; [name setImage:img]; 
}

@end
```